# Is there a more efficient way to filter large arrays than preg_match()?

Tags: php, search, array

I have a log that our web application builds. Each month it contains around 16,000 entries of a string with about the average sentence worth of text.

To filter/search through these in our admin panel the script uses `preg_match()` but this seems to be taking ages and timing out on the 30sec limit. I have isolated that it is indeed the `preg_match()` that causes the time out.

Is there a more efficient way to search through values in a large array for a users input?

Comment: Are you really using complicated regular expressions inside `preg_match` or just searching for a substring?

Comment: 16,000 entries could easily be loaded into notepad++ and you can run simple searches and regular expression searches. Why code? You could even write a macro do that automatically.

Comment: Just searching for a substring, and no I cannot use a desktop based program as our account managers (IT noobs) need to be able to search.

Comment: On a side note, is there a better method for using complicated regular expressions? - as I do this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would research `in_array()` and `array_search()` to see if they catch what you're looking for. Otherwise, use a for loop and use `stripos()` on each entry's text, which is my normal tool for searching in strings.

Comment: I cannot use in_array() or array_search() as they require an exact match. Third option is what im after! Thanks.